# Como criar uma função na linguagem J?

Tags: funções, característica-linguagem, j

Como criar uma função na linguagem J? Todos os exemplos que eu encontrei online mostram somente como descrever funções por meio de um *fork*:

```
media =: +/ % #
media 1 2 3 4
2.5
```

O código acima (`+/ % #`) é o mesmo que "somar todos os elementos do array" (`+/`), "achar o tamanho do array" (`#`) e dividir um pelo outro (`%`). O que está ok, mas eu gostaria de saber de um modo mais geral, como definir funções com, digamos, múltiplos parâmetros, múltiplas expressões no corpo da função, etc. J suporta esse tipo de coisa? Ou essa linguagem não tem funções tal como as linguagens mais comuns?

Comment: A pergunta que não quer calar, quem no mundo programa em J?

Comment: @PabloPalácios Bom, o pessoal do [codegolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) parece usar bastante, por que será né? rsrs

Comment: agora faz todo sentido!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não sou especialista em J, mas procurei algumas informações que possivelmente irão te ajudar.

Bem, se você deu uma olhada na documentação, viu que a palavra *function* não é tão comum em J. Henry Rich, escritor do [J for C programmers](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help804/jforc/contents.htm), assimila função ao termo *verbo* em J.

Como esse mesmo autor atesta, verbos só podem receber até dois argumentos (ou, na idiomática do J, operandos). Com isso, temos dois tipos de verbos, *monadics* ou *dyadics*, que recebem um e dois operandos respectivamente.

Em função disso, J nomeia os operandos automaticamente para você. No caso de um verbo *monadic*, o nome que será passado para as sentenças do corpo do verbo será o `y`. Na hora de chamar um verbo `monadic`, o operando deverá ficar a direita do verbo.

Para construir um verbo *monadic*:

```
soma1 =: monad define
y + 1
)
```

Repare que você pode passar tanto um único número quanto um array para o verbo que ele funcionará:

```
soma1 1
2
soma 1 2 3
2 3 4
```

Nos verbos *dyadic*, os nomes dos operandos serão `x` e `y`. Na hora de chamar o verbo, `x` deverá estar a sua esquerda e `y` deverá estar a sua direita. Para construir um verbo *dyadic*:

```
somaXproduto =: dyad define
(x + y) * x * y
)
```

A mesma observação sobre os tipos dos operandos feita para verbos *monadics* vale para os *dyadics*:

```
1 somaXproduto 2
6
1 2 3 somaXproduto 1 2 3
2 16 54
```

Um ponto interessante é que você pode ter um verbo dos dois tipos. Para construí-lo, você escreve primeiro a parte *monadic* e depois a parte *dyadic*, separadas por um `:`. Veja o exemplo:

```
soma1especial =: verb define
y + 1
:
x + y + 1
)
```

Caso o verbo seja chamado com apenas um operando, adicionará 1, e, se for chamado com 2 operandos, somará os dois a 1:

```
soma1especial 1
2
1 soma1especial 1
3
```

Além disso, tenho algumas observações. O resultado do verbo será o resultado da última sentença (linha) do verbo (se não me engano, assim como em Perl).

Outro ponto digno de nota é que, caso você crie um verbo que não utilize nenhum operando, você deverá, impreterivelmente, chamá-lo passando algum valor, podendo ser uma string vazia:

```
foo =: verb define
a =: 1
b =: 2
a + b
)

foo ''
3
```

Veja que nesse último exemplo eu não defini o tipo do verbo. Por padrão, quando você utiliza apenas `verb define`, sem adicionar o caso *dyadic*, o verbo será *monadic*. Não somente, esse exemplo mostra a utilização de múltiplas sentenças em um único verbo.

Além dessa sintáxe para criar verbos, há uma mais breve, para verbos que podem ser descritos em apenas uma linha:

```
soma1 := monad : 'y + 1'
soma1especial := dyad : 'x + y + 1'
```

Repare que o *texto* do verbo deve ficar entre aspas.

Por fim, lembro que em J, há também modificadores de verbos, como os advérbios, forks e hooks (e que não deixam de ser um tipo de função também).

O exemplo que você deu apresenta dois modificadores, o advérbio `/` e um *fork*, que não possui representação gráfica.

O `/` fará a inserção do verbo que estiver a sua esquerda entre os elementos do array que estiver a sua direita.

Já o *fork*, precisa de três verbos separados por espaços para funcionar. O resultado será uma função composta que poderá ser *monadic* ou *dyadic*. No primeiro caso, o do seu exemplo, teríamos o seguinte:

```
(f g h) y
```

Isso será traduzido da seguinte maneira:

```
(f y) g (h y)
```

No seu exemplo, `f` já é um verbo modificado o `+/`, que inserirá `+` entre os elementos de `y`. O resultado disso corresponderá ao operando `x` de `g`.

Do mesmo modo, `h` será substituído pelo verbo `#`, que retorna o tamanho de um array e corresponderá ao operando `y` de `g`.

Finalmente, `g` será substituído por `%`, que é um verbo *dyadic* e fará a divisão entre os resultados obtidos anteriormente.

A diferença entre um `fork` *monadic* de um *dyadic* está em sua tradução. Um exemplo seria `x (f g h) y` que seria traduzido para `(x f y) g (x h y)` e funcionará de maneira homóloga ao modo *monadic* explicado anteriormente.

Mágico, não?

Comment: Excelente! Por mim já está aceito (mas como é de praxe, vou aguardar mais um pouco dada a recompensa). Engraçado que, sem saber essa nomenclatura ("verbo"), eu tive bastante dificuldade de encontrar essa informação. Agora está tudo bem mais claro!

Comment: @mgibsonbr O livro que coloquei como referência é uma boa leitura, e cumpre muito bem essas lacunas entre linguagens de seres humanos e J.